# Convert Wordpress user registered date / time into unix timestamp

Tags: php, wordpress, timestamp

I need to convert a `user_registered` date from wordpress into a UNIX timestamp.

The output of the below returns

```
$get_users = get_users( array( 'blog_id' => get_current_blog_id() ) );
$user_id = $get_users[0]->ID;
$user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
$user_registered_date = $user_info->user_registered;
```

`$user_registered_date` returns `2017-01-17 15:43:18`

I need to convert the date into a UNIX timestamp. How would I go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP's builtin function [strtotime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) for this, for example

```
$user_registered_time_unix = strtotime($user_registered_date); // 1484664198
```

Answer (score 0):

The time is in GMT timezone, so "GMT" should be added to time string before converting.

```
$user_registered_time_unix = strtotime($user_registered_date . " GMT" );
```